# How search postgres with english number but return farsi/arabic?

Tags: sql, postgresql, grails-orm

I have Farsi and English number in a text column and need a query to search a number in both languages.

I used N prefix but It did not work.

Can someone explain is it possible that search multilingual numbers in Postgres?

for example I have these rows in my db:

```
name:
p1
p2
p3
p۱
p۲
```

and now when I run this query:

```
select  * 
from table 
where name = 'p1';
```

`p۱` was not returned. but I need return same numbers return query

Comment: The only way I can see is to use an `or` condition: `where name = 'p1' or name = 'p۲'`. To make that easier, create a function that turns `'p1'` into `'p۲'`

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that converts Farsi numbers to Arabic numbers and use that to search the table.

Comment: I have problem with query english number to return farsi number

Comment: I add new column in database and normalized data in that column, for search farsi number convert to english and query on  that normalized column. beside that I handle arabic and farsi similar alphabet

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace
    function Persian_Normalize(text text)
    returns text
    language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
-- variable declaration
    normalize_text text;
begin
    -- logic
    normalize_text = text;
    normalize_text = Replace(normalize_text, 'ك', 'ک');
    normalize_text = Replace(normalize_text, 'بِ', 'ب');
    normalize_text = Replace(normalize_text, 'زِ', 'ز');
    normalize_text = Replace(normalize_text, 'ذِ', 'ذ');
    normalize_text = Replace(normalize_text, 'ِشِ', 'ش');
    normalize_text = Replace(normalize_text, 'دِ', 'د');
    normalize_text = Replace(normalize_text, 'ِسِ', 'س');
    normalize_text = Replace(normalize_text, 'ى', 'ی');
    normalize_text = Replace(normalize_text, 'ي', 'ی');
    normalize_text = Replace(normalize_text, 'ئ', 'ی');
    normalize_text = Replace(normalize_text, 'ئ', 'ی');
    normalize_text = Replace(normalize_text, '۱', '1');
    normalize_text = Replace(normalize_text, '۲', '2');
    normalize_text = Replace(normalize_text, '۳', '3');
    normalize_text = Replace(normalize_text, '۴', '4');
    normalize_text = Replace(normalize_text, '۵', '5');
    normalize_text = Replace(normalize_text, '۶', '6');
    normalize_text = Replace(normalize_text, '۷', '7');
    normalize_text = Replace(normalize_text, '۸', '8');
    normalize_text = Replace(normalize_text, '۹', '9');
    normalize_text = Replace(normalize_text, '۰', '0');
    return normalize_text;
end ;
$$;
```

Use function:

```
select  * 
from table 
where Persian_Normalize(name)= Persian_Normalize('p1');
```